# Bootstrap pagination custom buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am using bootstrap pagination and I am using custom css to change the look of the pagination. The page numbers have no border initially but the border appears on hover and active states with a grey background. It has 4 buttons First, Previous, Next and Last that have a border initially. The same should happen to them on hover and active.

The problem is that when I hover over the 4 buttons, I get a strange effect. They move out of place.

```css
.pagination .page-link i{
    width:  34px;
    padding:  6px 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display:  flex;
    flex-direction:  column;
    justify-content:  center;
    align-items: center;
}
.pagination .page-link:hover .fas{
    border: none;
}
.pagination .page-link{
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:  #232323;
    margin-right: 3px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    display:  flex;
    flex-direction:  column;
    justify-content:  center;
    align-items: center;
    outline: none!important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.pagination .page-link:hover, .pagination .page-link:focus, .pagination .page-item.active .page-link{
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    color:  #232323;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d45e7e578e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="First">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">First</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Last">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

//Because you are changing the `margin-right` property on `.pagination .page-link:hover`

I was wrong about the earlier answer and editing for clarity. It wasn't margin-right property alone but also the bunch of other props changed on hover. I can't edit your entire code to suit your need. It won't serve the purpose of you learning to do it. The `:hover` should contain only the css props that need to change and everything else needs to be defined for the origin element itself. Also you are not overriding the `border-radius` property at the right place. Identify where the border-radius changes on hover and then you can apply the one you want to the right element.

Comment: I commented it out and I ma getting the same effect

Comment: It was not just the margin property. Sorry it wasn't the margin property at all but everything else applied on .pagination .page-link:hover, like you are setting the height, width and display properties on the hover, which is wrong. Also the border-radius property is applied through bootstrap overrides on hover. I can't edit the entire code for you. Inspect element properties and change them accordingly using dev tools. Classes added to :hover should ideally contain only those need to change and nothing else. I'm editing my answer to fit this.

Comment: I edited my post as per your suggestions. It is working better but I still need those margins for the 4 buttons

Comment: Add a separate class for those four elements and add margin to that class